# LEFT JOINs with multiple tables

Tags: mysql

**I have following tables:**

```
table users - PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
+---------+----------+-----------+
| user_id | username | realname  |
+---------+----------+-----------+
|       1 | peterpan | Peter Pan |
|       2 | bobfred  | Bod Fred  |
|       3 | sallybe  | Sally Be  |
|       6 | petersep | Peter Sep |
+---------+----------+-----------+

table users_groups - PRIMARY KEY (user_id, group_id)
+---------+----------+
| user_id | group_id |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | 1        |
| 1       | 2        |
| 2       | 1        |
| 2       | 2        |
| 3       | 6        |
| 3       | 9        |
| 6       | 6        |
| 6       | 9        |
+---------+----------+

table game - PRIMARY KEY (id)
+----+-------+
| id | game  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | Game1 |
| 2  | Game2 |
| 6  | Game6 |
| 9  | Game9 |
+----+-------+

table groups - PRIMARY KEY(group_id)
+----------+--------------+---------------+
| group_id | group_name   | group_desc    |
+----------+--------------+---------------+
| 1        | Groupname1   | Description1  |
| 2        | Groupname2   | Description2  |
+----------+--------------+---------------+

table group_game - PRIMARY KEY(group_id, game_id)
+----------+----------+
| group_id | game_id  |
+----------+----------+
| 1        | 1        |
| 1        | 2        |
| 2        | 6        |
| 2        | 9        |
+----------+----------+
```

**I want to display this (like a group list):**

```
+----+------------+--------------+---------------------+--------------+
| id | group name | group desc   | group members       | group games  |
+----+------------+--------------+---------------------+--------------+
|  1 | GroupName1 | Description1 | Peter Pan, Bob Fred | Game1, Game2 |
|  2 | GroupName2 | Description2 | Sally Be, Peter Sep | Game6, Game9 |
+----+------------+--------------+---------------------+--------------+
```

**Now I have this query but it gives me no rows (no error, just zero rows):**

```
SELECT
    g.group_name,
    g.group_id,
    g.group_desc,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ga.game SEPARATOR ', ') AS games,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u.realname SEPARATOR ', ') AS users
FROM groups g
LEFT JOIN users_groups ug1
    ON g.group_id=ug1.group_id
LEFT JOIN users u
    ON ug1.user_id=u.user_id
LEFT JOIN group_game gg
   ON g.group_id=gg.group_id
LEFT JOIN game ga
   ON gg.game_id=ga.id
GROUP BY g.group_name
```

How can I solve this problem or how can I write this query?

I just want to show a group list with all information (like group information, users of the groups, games of this group).

Comment: It seems very weird that the result would return 0 rows as there are rows in the group table. Try removing all the joins and groups (and CONCATs for good measure) and adding them back one by one until you find the issue.

Comment: Friendly reminder to list all the non-aggregate columns in `GROUP BY` clause. All other SQL dialects will punish you for it and if you turned ANSI mode on, MySQL will too! Learn to do it as best practices.

Comment: Also, I ran your schema and query in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aad91/2) and two rows certainly output! Do note results does not exactly match yours as last two game_ids is 3, 4 not 6, 9. And user_groups only have two distinct users: 1, 2.

Comment: Sry it was a typo fail :/ But to the GROUP BY thing. How should I do this, because if I leave GROUP BY away it just output one row

Comment: I think your sample data for `group_games` is incorrect (to match the expected result) INSERT INTO group_game VALUES(1, 1),(1, 2),(2, 3),(2, 4); and by making that data change, your query produces the expected result exactly. This suggests to me that if your query isn't producing rows that you don't have a representative set of sample data

Comment: the (v.good) point made by Parfait is to include `more detail` in the GROUP BY clause, not to remove it.  i.e. Include all non-aggregating columns, not just the first column. **GROUP BY g.group_name, g.group_id, g.group_desc**

Comment: Ok thanks. I corrected now the GROUP BY part. And sorry for the typo fail in the table of "game"

Comment: your query produces the expected result (if data is corrected) so I cannot offer a reason why you get zero rows except that the sample data does not adequately represent the actual data

Comment: I had a incorrect name for a table, sorry for that :/